# I want to rewrite a vhdl that includes the ieee library ieee.std_logic_1164.all into system verilog what should I do?

Tags: system-verilog

I am completely new to vhdl and system verilog. I have to rewite a vhdl file that includes the following lines:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

Do I have to include some similar libraries that comply with the system verilog standard?
How should the code look like in system verilog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SystemVerilog includes all of the types you need already built into the language. Check out the tutorials on [ASIC World](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/tutorial.html) for more info.